# Adding keyword on android apk file when uploading google play store

Tags: android

I uploaded the apk file to google play store. But i cannot find my project from google play store when i search my package name. How can i do for searching on google play store to detect my application.?

Comment: Are you sure the app has been published?  If you just created your Google Play store account, it may take some time before you can publish it.

Comment: @user2159988 just wait some time, if it's marked as published in your developer console it definitely will appear on GooglePlay.

Answer (score 1):

If your application name is for example The Best Application Of The World, and you are using Google Plays search, it will propably not show your app in search results. But if you enclose the name with quotes like "The Best Application Of The World" then Google Play search should show only your app and nothing else (if it is published).

Answer (score 0):

First assure your application successful **published** at right side of **google play console.**

If successful publish then it will appear in with a `1-24` hours.

I think it just has to do with `Google's server traffic` (many apps are waiting to be processed for accepting request).

Be happy it will be appear in shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The apps are usually published within a few hours, but it can take longer for the search system to be updated so that's why you sometimes can't search for it immediately after it is published.

If you want to get to the app after it has been published, use the reverse domain name of your application package:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.myapplication
```